Mail errors deluge
Is there any way to know if there's been an error during the sending process? (i.e. the receiver mail doesn't exist)
I am using the sendmail feature but I would like to know if I couldn't send the mail for any reason
I did do a try-catch but it seems deluge (zoho creator) doesn't recognise it as an error worthy of it, the function either executes until the end or doesn't recognise the exception
Option A:
void mail()
{
    sendmail
    [
        from :zoho.loginuserid
        to :" "
        cc:"salesmanager@zoho.com"
        reply to :"support@zohocreator.com"
        subject :"Team meeting"
        message :"Let's meet at 5"
    ];
    return "hey";
}

Option B
void email2()
{
    try 
    {
        sendmail
        [
            from :zoho.loginuserid
            to :"null"
            cc:"salesmanager@zoho.com"
            reply to :"support@zohocreator.com"
            subject :"Team meeting"
            message :"Let's meet at 4"
        ]
        info "aaaaa";
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        info e.message;
        // Displays the error message 
        info e;
        info "eeeee";
    }
}

